# How to Loop the FormCollection using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I need to Loop my FormCollection to get Id values from collection..

I have something like

```
collection[0]
collection[1]
collection[2]
collection[3]
collection[4]
collection[5]
collectoin[6]
```

I have 7 or more  keys I need to get second Index that means 1 3 5 7 9 11. something likethat.. 
I need to loop to get those values..

Can any body help me out..  using asp.net mvc..

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < collection.Count; i += 2)
{ 
    var value = collection[i.ToString()];
    // do whatever with value
}
```